# SSAS- MDX Assign fact row to dimension member base on calculation

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I am looking to calculate in the calc script something, so I can allocate a row from a fact table to a dimension member.

The business scenario is the following. I have a fact table that record customer credit and debit ( customer can do a lot of little loan) and a dimension Customer.I want to classify my customer base on his history of credit and debit on a given period.Classification of customer change over time.

Example
The rule is, if a customer balance (for a given period ) is over - 50 000, the classification is "large", if he have more than a record and have done a payement in the last 3 month he is a "P&P.If he doesn't own any money and have done a payement in the last 3 month its "regular".

My question is more about direction than a specific code,which way is the best to implement this kind of rule ?

Best Regards

Vincent Diallo-Nort

Comment: Wouldn't be easier/better to calculate that in the database and add the result to the customer table (if you have some kind of ETL process) ?

Comment: Or in the fact table you can add named calculation based on the current balance with the values you want and then create a degenerate dimension on that table. It will still be a separate dimension though. Not a part of the Customer one. ( Example of named calculation: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/660919/Introduction-to-Named-Calculations-in-SQL-Server-A )

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a fact table with a balance auto-updated status every day:

- check the rolling balance yesterday plus today's records.
- when the balance = 0, then remove a record.

Plus add a flow fact table with payments only.

Add measures:

- **LastChild** aggregation for the first fact table.
- **Sum** aggregation for the second fact table.

When it's done, you may apply a MDX calculation:

```
case 
    when [Measure].[Balance] > 50000 
    then "Large"
    when [Measure].[Payments] + ([Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Lag(1),[Measure].[Payments]) + ([Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Lag(2),[Measure].[Payments]) > 0
    then "P&P"
    else "Regular"
end
```

In order to give you answer in detail you have to provide more information about your data structure.